# jQuery UI draggable and sortable bug?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm trying to do some seemingly simple jQuery UI drag and drop, but am seeing some odd behavior. I display two s of classes. I want to drag and drop students between them...simple right? As soon as I grab and move the item, it jumps off from my mouse to the top of the HTML. I thought it might have something to do with the parent or mouseOffset options, but to no avail.

It seems to work fine if I set helper:"clone", but I don't want a copy of the object, I want to move it.

See fiddle here:

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/dddrhcv9/1/`
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: -1 for bypassing the warning to include code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work if you make them both sortable and use the connectWith property:

```
$('.child-list').sortable({
    connectWith: ".child-list"
}).disableSelection();
```

I updated your JSFiddle, and I think it gives you what you need:

http://jsfiddle.net/dddrhcv9/2/